# Do i need to clear map after assign new map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Here is an example :

```
pair< map<int, string>, map<int, string> > test;
test = data;
```

So do i need to call `clear` method before assign? Like this :

```
pair< map<int, string>, map<int, string> > test;
test.first.clear();
test.second.clear();
test = data;
```

Or first example is correct without memory leaks?

Comment: You are not allocating any memory with `new`, what do you expect to leak?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator%3D

Comment: "So do i need to call clear method before assign?" No you don't need to clear the maps. Why are you asking? Best you make a test case for such cases if you're unsure and examine with a tool like valgrind (or study the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator%3D) in 1st place).

Comment: okay, thanks, just my doubts.So map deletes a previous data by yourself when assign is called but which map? Map which get the data or map with the data?

Comment: Both maps will have the same data, from the right-hand side object.

Comment: The point of standard library classes is that they manage their own memory. You don't have to worry about them. Just treat them like an abstract data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/

Map constructor - constructs empty container with no elements.

Pair -Constructs a pair object with its elements value-initialized.

So, my guess is that there is no memory leak, plus you are not allocating any memory there so.